# Javascript regular expression issue for adding zero before decimal, the moment i enter decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

As I am doing amount validation :

`/^(([1-9]\d{0,8})(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{0,2})?)/g;`

This regex is working for those conditions :

1. its accepting only one decimal point
2. Before decimal its accepting 9 digits and after 2 digits.
3. I have given a `OR(|)` condition also , which accepts a decimal point in the beginning, and after that it only accepts 2 digits.

Could any tell me if at all i enter decimal point in the beginning, it would add a zero(0) as a prefix by itself before the decimal.

Comment: Please clarify... do you want the regex to add a zero (to which the answer is "it can't") or is all the regex stuff completely superfluous and you want to know how to modify the format of the number after a user has typed it in?

Comment: if i enter decimal point in the beginning , its should add a zero before it ?

Comment: So, you want to know how to prefix a 0 to a decimal number? When? After the user clicks something or moves away from the textbox? Why do you need to prefix a zero? Please add more details **to your question**. And remove the regex stuff because that's just going to confuse people.

Comment: i do need that regex stuff ,i am doing an amount validation which had one requirement .i.e if i enter a decimal point in the beginning, it should add a prefix zero before it. Along with that it should accept 9 digits before decimal and 2 digits after it

Comment: which is working fine .you could see i have also added a condition ./.d{0,2} in the OR part,this is allowing me to add a decimal point in the beginning, but along with that i want a zero to add as a prefix.I mean the number should look like 0.23

Comment: You need it in your code, but since it's "*working fine*", you **don't** need it in your question. It'll confuse people who think you are asking about regex, when in fact this question has nothing to do with regex.

Comment: @Aishwarya My answer fulfills your requirement including the validation http://stackoverflow.com/a/35508449/5678086

Comment: Your regex in question is also wrong. Use the one in my answer

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an event handler as below. If you put "." and enter some number, it will prepend that with "0". Now this includes validation of 9 digits - . - 2 digits also

```js
function addZero(handle) {
    if (handle.value[0]==".") {
       handle.value = "0"+handle.value;
    }
}

function checkAmount() {
    var curAmt = document.getElementById("amount").value;
    if (!/^(([0-9]{0,9}\.[0-9]{0,2})|([0-9]{0,9}))$/.test(curAmt)) {
       alert("Enter valid amount");
    }
    else {
       alert("Amount is valid");
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="amount" type="text" onkeypress="addZero(this)">

<input type="submit" onclick="checkAmount()">
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a leading zero, you can use standard JavaScript features:

```js
var input = '.15';

var formatted = Number(input).toFixed(2);

$('#result').text( formatted );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```